# 16.04 doesn't show on update manager

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and I keep it up to date through Software Updater.

I want to upgrade to 16.04 and I have waited for the 16.04.1 release to do it.

When I run the Software Updater GUI with the option to inform about only LTS versions nothing is shown. However, when I check the option to inform about all versions, 15.10 is offered.
When I run

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

again 15.10 is offered and when I run

```
do-release-upgrade -cd
```

then 14.10 is offered.

Any clues on what is wrong?

EDIT

Given up trying to find out why the upgrade wouldn't show on `do-release-upgrade` and upgraded through the live cd as sugested by @Stormlord below.

Comment: `do-release-upgrade -d` will offer 16.04, if 14.04 is installed. If not then something is wrong with you system.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe 16.04 has not been deployed to the mirror server you are using yet. There's not *the* Ubuntu server, but a system of mirror servers around the world, for example serving different countries. The official release of 16.04.1 (the first point release of the new LTS, that triggers the "there's a new LTS available" message) was just two days ago. It may well be that it takes a few days more to be available from all mirror servers around the world.

Comment: Thanks, @HenningKockerbeck, but I just tried changing the server and it still doesn't show 16.04. I think there must be something wrong with my system. Anyway, I'm still trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: `uname -a` gives?

Comment: pietro@pietro-desktop:~$ uname -a  

Linux pietro-desktop 4.4.0-31-lowlatency #50-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 13 00:58:45 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  
I switched to Ubuntu Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a guess than an actual answer.

If you update the package-lists do you get any warning or errors?

```
 sudo apt-get update
 -- go through and check for warnings
```

And are the sources good?

```
 cat /etc/apt/sources.list
 -- check if something important is out-commented.
```

Comment: Thanks. No warnings on `sudo apt-get update` and the only out-commented sources are *deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main* and *deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main*

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason `do-release-upgrade` doesn't work for you, go ahead and download the 16.04.1 .iso, create the Live CD and start your system with it.  One of the installation options will be to upgrade your current system the same way `do-release-upgrade` would upgrade it.

Comment: Thanks. In the end, that is what I did. I couldn't figure out why the upgrade wouldn't show on `do-release-upgrade`. Given up trying and upgraded through the live cd.